# Put csv files in separate pandas dataframes depending on filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list that contains file names. I want to parse directory and read all the files starting with every element from list and store it in dataframe

Eg:

```
list1=[abc,bcd,def]
```

Directory:

```
abc1.txt   
abc2.txt
abc3.txt

bcd1.txt
bcd2.txt
bcd3.txt
```

The output should be such that Files starting with  'abc' should be in one pandas dataframe and files starting with 'bcd' in other dataframe etc

My code:

```
 dfs = []
 for exp in expnames:
     for files in filenames:
         if files.startswith(exp):
              dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file_path+files,sep=',',header=None))
      big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will create a dictionary of `DataFrames` where each `DataFrame` consists of all files matching the first three letters of our "expressions" (i.e. `abc`, `def` et.c.). The keys in the dictionary are the same three letters:

```
# Some dummy data
filenames = ['abcdefghijkl.txt', 'abcdef.txt',  'defghijk.txt']

# List of combination of certain letters 
exps = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

dataframes = {} 
for filename in filenames:
    _df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    key = exps[exps.index(filename[:3])]

    try: 
        dataframes[key] = pd.concat([dataframes[key], _df], ignore_index=True)
    except KeyError:
        dataframes[key] = _df



print(dataframes['abc'])

    a   b   c
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12
2   1   2   3
3   4   5   6

print(dataframes['def'])
    a   b   c
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12
```

The contents of the files above are:

*abcdefghijkl.txt*

```
a,b,c
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

*abcdef.txt*

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

*defghijkl.txt*

```
a,b,c
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

Comment: This is not recommended. `concat` in a loop is inefficient and a [better alternative is provided explicitly in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Comment: This is false. The docs state that `concat` in an explicit for loop is less efficient than a list comprehension but it doesn't state that it is *not recommended* to use `concat` in a loop for other reasons than performance. This is true for `python` in general. As you know, performance is not everything. Otherwise you can start down-voting every answer on SO that uses explicit for loops instead of list comprehension. Good luck, @jpp.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you have a directory where there could be several other files besides the ones you want to read.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dfs = { }

for f in os.listdir(dirname):
   for k in list1:
       if f.startswith(k):
          try:
             dfs[k].concat(pd.read_csv(dirname+f, sep=',', header=None))
          except KeyError:
             dfs[k] = pd.read_csv(dirname+f, sep=',', header=None))
```

Comment: There is no `DataFrame.concat()` method so this will break. You need to call `pd.concat()` with a list of `DataFrames` or use `DataFrame.append()`.