# Merge files with similar name convention to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

I have a list of files stored in directory such as

```
filenames=[
        abc_1.txt
        abc_2.txt
        abc_3.txt

        bcd_1.txt
        bcd_2.txt
        bcd_3.txt
       ]

pattern=[abc]
```

I want to read multiple txt files into one dataframe such  that all files starting with abc will be in one dataframe then all all filename starting with bcd etc.

My code:

```
file_path = '/home/iolie/Downloads/test/'
filenames = os.listdir(file_path)


prefixes = list(set(i.split('_')[0] for i in filenames))

for prefix in prefixes:
    print('Reading files with prefix:',prefix)
    for file in filenames: 
        if file.startswith(prefix):
            print('Reading files:',file)
            list_of_dfs = [pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path, file), header=None) ],ignore_index=True)]
            final = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

This code doesnt't append but overwrites the dataframe. Can someone help wih this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put csv files in separate pandas dataframes depending on filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118137/put-csv-files-in-separate-pandas-dataframes-depending-on-filename)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183124/discussion-on-question-by-tejas-shah-merge-files-with-similar-name-convention-to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better idea than creating an arbitrary number of unlinked dataframes is to output a **dictionary of dataframes**, where the key is the prefix:

```
from collections import defaultdict

filenames = ['abc_1.txt', 'abc_2.txt', 'abc_3.txt',
             'bcd_1.txt', 'bcd_2.txt', 'bcd_3.txt']

dd = defaultdict(list)

for fn in filenames:
    dd[fn.split('_')[0]].append(fn)

dict_of_dfs = {}
for k, v in dd.items():
    dict_of_dfs[k] = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fn) for fn in v], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I want to perform certain operations further and it would be better to perform those on dataframes. If possible, can you suggest me any modifications in original code to fix the issue.

Comment: @tejasshah, Sure. So your dictionary values **are** dataframes. You can operate on them via operating on (for example) `dict_of_dfs['abc']`. If you don't believe me, try `type(dict_of_dfs['abc'])`.