# Should we use for loop or list comprehension when creating DataFrames from multiple data sources?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is related to @jpp:s answer in [Merging files with similar name convention to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152892/merge-files-with-similar-name-convention-to-a-dataframe) and the decision to mark an earlier thread ([Put csv-files in separate dataframes depending on filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118137/put-csv-files-in-separate-pandas-dataframes-depending-on-filename)) as duplicate because the three answers in that thread were either not working (2/3) or poor (1/3).

Disregarding the answers that were not working, one answer (my answer) was said to be of poor quality because ["using `concat` within a for loop is explicitly not recommended by the docs"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118608/3471881).

---

**The criticised method**:

```
dataframes = {}
for filename in filenames:
    _df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    key = filename[:3]
    try:
       dataframes[key] = pd.concat([dataframes[key], _df], ignore_index=True)
    except KeyError:
       dataframes[key] = _df
```

**The accepted method** (`dd` is a dictionary where each value is a list of filenames and each key is the first three characters of each filename):

```
dict_of_dfs
for k, v in dd.items():
    dict_of_dfs[k] = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fn) for fn in v], ignore_index=True)
```

---

Now I agree that list comprehension within the `concat` call (the accepted method) is *more efficient* than a for loop where `concat` is called on each `DataFrame`.

But does this mean that we should **always** create `DataFrames` from multiple data sources by using list comprehension in the `concat` call (or `append`) and that using a for loop is so **poor** that it is actually **wrong**? And what about readability? I personally (of course) think my criticised method is more readable.

---

If we read the `pandas` docs on [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) we learn that neither for loops or list comprehension are "recommended methods for generating DataFrames":

> The following, **while not recommended methods for generating DataFrames**, show two ways to generate a DataFrame from multiple data sources.
>
> Less efficient:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
>>> for i in range(5):
...     df = df.append({'A': i}, ignore_index=True)
>>> df

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

> More efficient:

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['A']) for i in range(5)],
...           ignore_index=True)

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

---

So. My questions are as follows:

1. Is looping and using `concat` on multiple data sources to create one or multiple instance(s) of `DataFrame` so **poor** that it is **wrong**?
2. Should we always use list comprehension in a case like this?
3. The docs don't seem to recommend using neither list comprehension or for loop, so what is the **recommended** way of creating `DataFrame`(s) from multiple data sources?

---

I really appreciate your answers @piRSquared and @jpp. I'm still not convinced about the categorical dismissal of `concat` in for loops as being **poor** to the point of being **wrong** while list comprehensions are **correct** and **accepted**.

Given the following test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(0, 25000), 'B': np.arange(0, 25000)})

for i in range(0, 50):
    df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Methods:

```
def conc_inside_loop(filenames):
    df = None
    for filename in filenames:

        if df is None:
           df = pd.read_csv(filename)
           continue

        df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(filename)], ignore_index=True)

    return df

def conc_list_comprehension(filenames):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames], ignore_index=True)
```

Times:

```
>> %timeit -n 10 conc_inside_loop(glob.glob('*.csv'))
460 ms ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


>> %timeit -n 10 conc_list_comprehension(glob.glob('*.csv'))
363 ms ± 32.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Obviously list comprehension *is more efficient* (I already said that I understand that). But the differences are not huge. **I don't think** you can call one method poor to the point of being **wrong** and the other one **correct** given the differences we see here.

As stated by @piRSquared the last question is too broad. But a third way would be to use `concat` outside the for loop:

```
def conc_outside_loop(filenames):
    
    df_list = []
    for filename in filenames:
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

    return pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

>> %timeit -n 10 conc_outside_loop(glob.glob('*.csv'))
344 ms ± 23.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is looping and using `concat` on multiple data sources to create one or multiple instance(s) of `DataFrame` so **poor** that it is **wrong**?

Yes!  Pandas is great.  But you should avoid at all cost the unnecessary production of Pandas objects.  Creating Pandas objects can be expensive, DataFrames more than Series but this is probably `True` for all python.  For the "criticized" method:  Within a loop you create a Pandas object that will be overwritten in the next iteration of the loop.  You should instead think how to gather your data in order to produce the Pandas object at the end of the gathering.

> 2. Should we always use list comprehension in a case like this?

No! As I said above, think of it as gathering data in preparation for the construction of the Pandas object.  A comprehension is only one such way to gather.

> 3. The docs don't seem to recommend using neither list comprehension or for loop, so what is the **recommended** way of creating `DataFrame`(s) from multiple data sources?

This is too broad.  A case can be made for many approaches.  Just don't use `concat` or `append` in a loop.  I'd call that wrong just about every time.

And by "every time" I don't actually mean "every time".  What I **DO** mean is that you should never create a dataframe at some point prior to a loop, then loop and at each iteration go through the trouble of appending something to the prior initialized dataframe.  Every iteration becomes very expensive.  In the case of the "Accepted" answer: it assigns a dataframe to a dictionary key and is then left alone.  It isn't repeatedly messed with.

Comment: Your answer is better, so I'm deleting mine. I'd add something that OP seems to have missed. That the loops he describes are over different iterables. One is the full list of filenames, the other is a categorized dictionary with list values, a much smaller iterable. They aren't comparable.

Comment: I like this, so does 3 mean that both methods (the accepted/the criticised) are  bad?

Comment: @jpp tbf the question isn't about the iterable because we could just remove that whole problem and the question still stands - `concat` in loop or with list comprehension? Or neither?

Comment: @piRSquared in a case where we are talking about csv files, would it be better to read them with another library (i.e. `csv`), combining them to a `list of dictionaries` and then just using `pd.DataFrame.from_records`?

Comment: @user3471881, I couldn't help adding *another* answer looking at the problem from another angle.

Comment: Was hoping that you could expand a little bit on the dismissal of `concat` within a loop as **wrong**, given the performance output I have now provided in the question, @piRSquared. I agree that applying a method or creating an instance of something multiple times even though we could apply it fewer times (if we just restructured our code) is generally **bad** but I don't necessarily think it is **wrong**.

Comment: Clearly this is a matter of opinion.  If you did this, your results should be correct.  But answers are often more than just producing correct results.  As answerers, we should hold ourselves to a higher standard and present options that represent good practice.  That requires us to be opinionated.  I don't believe a long drawn out answer is required to explain why doing this in a loop is a bad idea.  Its essentially asking "Should I created and overwrite and expensive to build object many times when I could do it much fewer times?".

Answer (score 4):

Let's be clear, `pd.DataFrame.append` / `pd.concat` in a loop is **not recommended**. [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156620/9209546) explains why, the docs are also explicit on that matter.

The reason lies in how NumPy arrays are structured. You can't append / concatenate them efficiently; these operations require making copies of data. The operations are memory intensive and generally inefficient.

As such, the "accepted" method is the lesser of two evils, as you're performing a relatively small number of `pd.concat` calls versus one for *every filename in the input list* via the "criticized" method.

#### Concatenate just once

You can concatenate *all* your dataframes and then perform a `GroupBy` operation:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fn).assign(file=fn.split('_')[0]) for fn in v],
               ignore_index=True)

dict_of_dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('file')))
```

The key, pardon the pun, is to reduce the number of concatenation operations.